# Compare list with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript, angular-material2, angular6, cypress

I hope you can help me..

I would like to write a "Cypress commands" which allows to test that a list containing a name and an id is well displayed.

template:

```
<mat-option 
  *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers$ | async" 
  [value]="user.id" 
  class="option-ldap-user-content"
>
  <span 
    class="ldap-user-name"
    classToApply="bold"
    appColorSearchedLetters 
    [text]="user.name" 
    [search]="addLdapUserForm.get('userSearchCtrl').value"
  ></span> |
  <small
    class="ldap-user-id"
    classToApply="bold" 
    appColorSearchedLetters 
    [text]="user.id" 
    [search]="addLdapUserForm.get('userSearchCtrl').value"
  ></small>
</mat-option>
```

commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('expectLdapUsersListToBe', (list1, list2) => {
  const ldapUserNames = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserNames);

  ldapUserNames.should('have.length', list1.length);

  ldapUserNames.each(($item, index) => {
    cy.wrap($item).contains(list1[index]);
  });
  const ldapUserIds = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserIds);

  ldapUserIds.should('have.length', list2.length);

  ldapUserIds.each(($item, index) => {
    cy.wrap($item).contains(list2[index]);
  });
});
```

e2e-spec.js:

```
it.only(`should display filtered list according to search string`, () => {
  cy.get(ADMINISTRATION_DOM.expPanel.expPanelAddUser).click();

  cy
    .get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.inputs.userSearchCtrl)
    .should('be.empty')
    .type(`e`);

  cy
    .get(`.multi-match`)
    .contains('7 people are matching this search.')
    .should('be.visible');

      // cy.expectLdapUsersListToBe(expected7LdapUsers); NOT WORKS
  cy.expectLdapUsersListToBe(expected7LdapUsersIds, expected7LdapUsersName);

...

  const expected7LdapUsers = [
    ['id1', 'UserName1'],
    ['id2', 'UserName2'],
    ['id3', 'UserName3'],
    ['id4', 'UserName4'],
    ['id5', 'UserName5'],
    ['id6', 'UserName6'],
    ['id7', 'UserName7'],
  ];

  const expected7LdapUsersIds = [
    'id1',
    'id2',
    'id3',
    'id4',
    'id5',
    'id6',
    'id7',
  ];

  const expected7LdapUsersName = [
    'UserName1',
    'UserName2',
    'UserName3',
    'UserName4',
    'UserName5',
    'UserName6',
    'UserName7',
  ];
```

I have written a command that works for the moment and that verifies that the names and ids is well displayed. Except that I test it with 2 lists.
I wish there was only one.
Is someone someone to help me please?

I test something like that but it's not working :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('expectLdapUsersListToBe', listOptions => {
  const ldapUserNames = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserNames);
  const ldapUserIds = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserIds);

  ldapUserNames.should('have.length', listOptions.length);
  ldapUserIds.should('have.length', listOptions.length);

  listOptions.forEach(($item, index) => {
    const item = cy.wrap($item);

    expect(item).to.contain(cy.wrap(ldapUserNames)[index]);
    expect(item).to.contain(cy.wrap(ldapUserIds)[index]);
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `but it's not working :` Could you elaborate? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: When I'm using one list like that : 
`cy.expectLdapUsersListToBe(expected7LdapUsers);`   
I have this error :   
`TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function.`

Comment: That would point to an issue with your indexing. It would appear that you cannot use `[]` on a cypress-wrapped object, or at least not in this case. What is the purpose of wrapping `ldapUserNames` and `ldapUserIds` before attempting to index them?

Comment: Perhaps did you mean `expect(item).to.contain(cy.wrap(ldapUserNames[index]));`, or just `expect(item).to.contain(ldapUserNames[index]);`?

Comment: The goal is to have a cleaner code.
So a list with 2 arguments is different from 2 lists.
And I wish to have only one list. That's all.

Suppose I have 5 arguments in my list, should I make 5 lists to be able to test my case?
It's not good at all.  

So, again, my question is how can I do to test a list with 2 arguments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my commands that I use for now.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'expectLdapUsersListToBe',
  (listUserNames, listUserIds) => {
    const ldapUserNames = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserNames);

    ldapUserNames.should('have.length', listUserNames.length);

    ldapUserNames.each(($item, index) => {
      cy.wrap($item).contains(listUserNames[index]);
    });
    const ldapUserIds = cy.get(ADD_LDAP_USER_DOM.texts.ldapUserIds);

    ldapUserIds.should('have.length', listUserIds.length);

    ldapUserIds.each(($item, index) => {
      cy.wrap($item).contains(listUserIds[index]);
    });
  }
);
```

test :

```
cy.expectLdapUsersListToBe(expected7LdapUsersName, expected7LdapUsersIds);
```

But as I said in my initial question, I wish to have a list and not 2.
Which means a single list with id and name expected.
My first example is deprecated.

Thank you all the same for this booster shot, it's a presentation error..

Comment: Oh wow, I was way off. I've deleted my answer as it seems to be inaccurate, in addition to not solving the problem.